# sending email workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a workflow to send an e-mail to all Community Members, but it's sending the e-mail just to users that are domain members, not to all members.  It's not working for users with Gmail etc. 
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Indeed it works for external users too, what I really want is to configure a lookup for users inside the members of (in my case organicos), so I don't have to type address by address, I want to make a dynamically email list. Thanks for advance.[image]

Comment: What do you have in the "To" field of your email?  And what version of SharePoint Designer are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint Designer 2013.  In the "To" I have "Organic Members", Organic is my community site.

Comment: "Organic Members" is a permissions group, correct?  Who is listed in that group?

Comment: Yes, it is Sharepoint Group. I have users that are from my organization (AD users) and users form outside, eg. morainelake@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

If your workflow is 2013 style, you can only email users. You can't email to outside addresses. Two choices - either put the email call in a 2010 style workflow and call that from your 2013 workflow, or, if you don't really need the functionality of a 2013 workflow, redo it in 2010 style. It's a big pain, driving us crazy as well.

Comment: I use SP designer 2013, but 2010 style. I have tried this site but it does not work. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4#bm2